# Selenium can't access dead object/The element reference is stale

Tags: python, django, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I am following [guide](http://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/) to learn TDD with python. At [some point](http://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/book/chapter_05.html#_creating_our_production_database_with_migrate), after doing migrations, the output of command `python3 functional_tests.py` should be (according to book):

```
self.fail('Finish the test!')
AssertionError: Finish the test!
```

But I am getting error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: Given css selector expression "tr" is invalid: TypeError: can't access dead object
```

And after trying second (and more) time:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: The element reference is stale. Either the element is no longer attached to the DOM or the page has been refreshed.
```

I've been googling and searching SO for similar problems, but didn't find one that could help me solve the issue.
I am using geckodriver, and adding it's path to `PATH`.

```
Django==1.8.7
selenium==3.0.2
Mozilla Firefox 50.0.2
(X)Ubuntu 16.04
```

Should I switch to Chrome? It's not trivial, it would require some time from me, but can it work? Is more like Firefox or Selenium? I don't think it's code related - I cloned [repo for chapter 5](https://github.com/hjwp/book-example/tree/chapter_05) and same crash is happening.

Comment: IMHO the support for Chrome seems to be much better. It is kind of trivial, get chromedriver and chromium via apt (sorry just debian cmds/names at hand) and symlink chromium to like /usr/bin/chrome and you are done (concerning changing to chromium).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the book is expecting you to use Selenium 2, not Selenium 3.  v3 has quite different behaviour with regards to implicit waits (and quite a few bugs last time I checked) so it's simplest to stick with Selenium 2 for now.

Have another look at the installation instructions: http://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/book/pre-requisite-installations.html

Answer (score 5):

The error arises because earlier in the chapter we add a redirect after a POST request. The page briefly refreshes, and that can screw up Selenium. If you want to stick with Selenium 3, I found a fix for this on the blog for the book: http://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/how-to-get-selenium-to-wait-for-page-load-after-a-click.html.

Basically, you add a method to the NewVisitorTest class that lets you to wait for the page to reload, and then continues with the assert tests.

```
...
from contextlib import contextmanager
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions import staleness_of

class NewVisitorTest(unittest.TestCase):
    ...
    @contextmanager
    def wait_for_page_load(self, timeout=30):
        old_page = self.browser.find_element_by_tag_name("html")
        yield WebDriverWait(self.browser, timeout).until(
            staleness_of(old_page)
        )
    ...
    def test_can_start_list_and_retrieve_it_later(self):
        ...
        inputbox.send_keys("Buy peacock feathers")
        inputbox.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

        with self.wait_for_page_load(timeout=10):
            self.check_for_row_in_list_table("1: Buy peacock feathers")

        inputbox = self.browser.find_element_by_id("id_new_item")
        inputbox.send_keys("Use peacock feathers to make a fly")
        inputbox.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

        with self.wait_for_page_load(timeout=10):
            self.check_for_row_in_list_table("1: Buy peacock feathers")
            self.check_for_row_in_list_table("2: Use peacock feathers to make a fly")
```